# Not able to promote the package to production after removing metadata

Tags: managed-package, 2gp

I removed some metadata components from my 2GP package. I had gotten the access to this feature by logging a case in partner portal.

After removing the metadata, I was able to create a new package version, but on promoting it to production, I get this error

```
ERROR running force:package:beta:version:promote:  Missing message package_version_promote:hasMetadataRemovedWarning for locale en_US.
```

Comment: Have you missed any other steps from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_remove_md_components.htm)?

Comment: Doesn't seem so. Followed everything

Comment: I suggest raising another support case if you have followed all the instructions and find this doesn't work.

Comment: (You could try debugging the CLI to see if you get any additional detail in the debug output...?)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an sfdx bug. You probably should create an issue https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/issues

Comment: For me this isn't an answer, but rather should have been a comment against the question...